# Rename files in a folder

Tags: r

I have to rename a list of files in a folder so that:

From file named:

```
> myfile_000.txt
> myfile_001.txt
>  ......
```

to file named:

```
> myfile_1.txt
> myfile_2.txt
> .......
```

Total files = 156

I used the following script:

```
> file.rename(list.files(pattern="myfile_*.txt", paste0("myfile_", 1:156)))
```

But without success.

Error:

> Error in file.rename(list.files(pattern = "myfile_*.txt", paste0("myfile_",  :
>     argument "to" is missing, with no default

Comment: Well, what happened when you used the script? Also, "can anyone help me please" is unnecessary; please don't include it in your questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message tells you, that you didn't specify the new names. It should work if you change the position of one `)`:

```
file.rename(list.files(pattern="myfile_*.txt"), paste0("myfile_", 1:156))
```

Comment: Ok, just solved! Thank you a lot!